# Dynamic PlotRange

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I am trying to set up a GUI to dynamically display and compare data. Based on an example from the [Documentation of IntervalSlider](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalSlider.html) I wanted to have dynamic control over the visible `PlotRange` using the `IntervalSlider` but found some unexpected behaviour. Let's take the code from the Documentation as working example:

```
DynamicModule[{data, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, int, w = 400, h = 30},
  data = FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2004"];
  ymin = Min[Last /@ data]; 
  ymax = Max[Last /@ data]; {xmin, xmax} = 
  FromDate /@ data[[{1, -1}, 1]];
  Column[{
    Show[DateListPlot[data, ImageSize -> w, Joined -> True], 
       PlotRange -> {Dynamic[int], {ymin, ymax}}],
    IntervalSlider[Dynamic[int], {xmin, xmax, 1}, 
       ImageSize -> {400, 30}, MinIntervalSize -> 1],
    DateListPlot[data, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
       ImageSize -> {w, h}, AspectRatio -> h/w, Joined -> True, 
       Epilog -> {Opacity[0.5], Orange, 
       Dynamic[Rectangle @@ Thread[{int, {ymin, ymax}}]]}]}]]
```

The expected output is:

[image]

However in the most recent Version

```
$Version
|Out> "11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016)"
```

[image]

The plot misses all `FrameTicks` and `GridLines`. If I use this approach in my case It shows `FrameTicks`, but fails to update them once I scroll off the initial range. Any ideas why this happens and how to work around this?

As a side question: Note the funny `Show[<plot>, PlotRange->{Dynamic....}]` construct. Apparently `DateListPlot` (and others) don't accept a `Dynamic` `PlotRange` directly. Does anybody know why this is the case?

Comment: Show passes PlotRange directly to Graphics which can handle Dynamic values, or better, FrontEnd can handle them. Top level plotting functions often need those values to calculate some intermediate things (axis position/filling maybe) so they can't take Dynamic head.

Comment: you get the grid lines by explicitly giving the options `GridLines` to `Show`. As per the ticks, do you mean that you want the y axis to be automatically adjusted to the actual data shown in the selected range?

Answer (score 3):

I posted the solution to this problem with an animated GIF of the results under the duplicate posting in the Mathematica Forum:

[solution to making this plot properly](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1087017)

---

Here is the same code that will dynamically change the ticks as the sliders are moved. The key to making this work is to get rid of the Show[]. The DateListPlot must be in the Dynamic[] so it gets redrawn when the sliders change. Show[] seems to limit what can be redrawn and messes up the format of the ticks. I added a popup at the bottom for the number of ticks. This version (even if you delete the popup and fix the number of ticks) is much better than the previous one (above).

```
DynamicModule[{data, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, ticks, ticknum = 4, int, 
  w = 400, h = 30}, 
 data = TimeSeries[FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2004"]];
 ymin = Min[data["Values"]];
 ymax = Max[data["Values"]]; {xmin, xmax} = {data["FirstTime"], 
   data["LastTime"]};
 int = {xmin, xmax};
 ticks = (xmax - xmin)/5*Range[4] + xmin;
 Column[{Dynamic[
    DateListPlot[data, ImageSize -> w, Joined -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {ticks, None}}, 
     DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "YearShort"}, 
     GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {int, Automatic}]], 
   IntervalSlider[
    Dynamic[int, {(int = #) &, (ticks = (int[[2]] - 
              int[[1]])/(ticknum + 1)*Range[ticknum] + 
          int[[1]]) &}], {xmin, xmax, 1}, ImageSize -> {400, 30}, 
    MinIntervalSize -> 1], 
   DateListPlot[data, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
    ImageSize -> {w, h}, AspectRatio -> h/w, Joined -> True, 
    Epilog -> {Opacity[0.5], Orange, 
      Dynamic[Rectangle @@ Thread[{int, {ymin, ymax}}]]}], 
   Row[{"Number of Ticks: ", 
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[ticknum], Range[10]]}]}]]
```

The only downside of the version above is that if you change the number of ticks in the popup, it does not redraw the plot -- you must move (or just click on) a slider. If you want the popup to instantly change the graph, you must force a variable inside the plot Dynamic[DateListPlot[...]] to change (such as the variable ticks). I added a function to the popup dynamic that will run after selection to change the variable ticks. This forces the redraw and I believe it has the behavior you are looking for.

```
DynamicModule[{data, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, ticks, ticknum = 4, int, 
  w = 400, h = 30}, 
 data = TimeSeries[FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2004"]];
 ymin = Min[data["Values"]];
 ymax = Max[data["Values"]]; {xmin, xmax} = {data["FirstTime"], 
   data["LastTime"]};
 int = {xmin, xmax};
 ticks = (xmax - xmin)/5*Range[4] + xmin;
 Column[{Dynamic[
    DateListPlot[data, ImageSize -> w, Joined -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {ticks, None}}, 
     DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "YearShort"}, 
     GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {int, Automatic}]], 
   IntervalSlider[
    Dynamic[int, {(int = #) &, (ticks = (int[[2]] - 
              int[[1]])/(ticknum + 1)*Range[ticknum] + 
          int[[1]]) &}], {xmin, xmax, 1}, ImageSize -> {400, 30}, 
    MinIntervalSize -> 1], 
   DateListPlot[data, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
    ImageSize -> {w, h}, AspectRatio -> h/w, Joined -> True, 
    Epilog -> {Opacity[0.5], Orange, 
      Dynamic[Rectangle @@ Thread[{int, {ymin, ymax}}]]}], 
   Row[{"Number of Ticks: ", 
     PopupMenu[
      Dynamic[ticknum, {(ticknum = #) &, (ticks = (int[[2]] - 
                int[[1]])/(ticknum + 1)*Range[ticknum] + 
            int[[1]]) &}], Range[10]]}]}]]
```

Comment: I've copied the code as we try to avoid link only answers. You never know when they become obsolete. Gif was too big though.